# Setting the rate at which RemoteIO Audio unit render callbacks are called

Tags: ios, core-audio, remoteio

I've setup RemoteIO audio unit render callbacks for both input and ouput. I'd like the render callbacks to be called less often. How can I specify the rate at which they're called?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The callbacks get called once per buffer, so you can make them get called less often by specifying a bigger buffer size. At a sample rate of 44.1 kHz with a (huge) buffer size of 8192 samples you get about 2/10 of a second between buffer calls.

Audio callbacks can't be spaced out more than this because they exist to do per-buffer processing of incoming/outgoing audio. If you don't run the callback on every buffer, you no longer have realtime audio.